# How can I prevent users from entering invalid e-mail addresses at registration?

Tags: users, emails

Sometimes users mistakenly input the wrong e-mail address upon user registration.  When this happens, they are unable to activate their account, because the password is e-mailed to their e-mail address (or, in my case, I'm actually using Logintoboggan, but they still need to click the link in their e-mail before their account can be activated).

Often in this situation, the user will realize their mistake and simply re-register.  This is ok, but then I have to clean up the accounts that never get activated, which is a pain.  I've noticed that the Drupal 7 registration will accept a bad domain in the e-mail address by default (for example, yahoo.co.jap, which is an invalid TLD).  When I realized this, I thought surely someone has already written a module to cover this use case (making sure users input a valid e-mail address on registration), but I was unable to find it.  Does such a module exist?

Comment: I haven't seen such a module, and I believe one of the reasons is that the topic is _significantly_ more complex than one might think. Read this text for reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: re: @Letharion's comment above, it is pretty complex.  But, you could do something in a custom validation script along the lines of pinging the baselevel server, eg, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239068/ping-site-and-return-result-in-php and then putting a warning up if, say [www.]HOSTNAME.TLD wasn't pingable. That would catch most of the main mail servers at least.

Comment: or, my bad, use http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal validates the email since Drupal 5; since Drupal 7, [valid_email_address()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/valid_email_address/7) (the function used to validate the email entered during registration, or when editing a user account) calls [filter_var()](http://php.net/filter_var).
The code used to validate the email address doesn't check if the domain exists, the username doesn't contain typos, or the domain has an active email server. While it would be possible to check if the domain has an email server by looking at its MX records with [checkdnsrr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php), it would be more difficult to verify if the username is correct, as most of the SMTP hosts doesn't return a useful value for the VRFY command (which means they always return ERROR, or OK).

Notice that the documentation for [getmxrr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmxrr.php) contains the following note.

> This function should not be used for the purposes of address verification. Only the mailexchangers found in DNS are returned, however, according to [RFC 2821](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2821) when no mail exchangers are listed, `$hostname` itself should be used as the only mail exchanger with a priority of 0.

I would rather do as [@Letharion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/1625/letharion) suggested, and implement `hook_cron()` to get ride of those accounts created by users who didn't type their email correctly. For Drupal 7, I would use the following code.

```
function mymodule_cron_queue_info() {
  $queues['mymodule_delete_users'] = array(
    'worker callback' => 'user_delete_user', 
    'time' => 30,
  );

  return $queues;
}

function mymodule_cron() {
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();

  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user')
    ->entityCondition('entity_id', 1, '>')
    ->propertyCondition('access', 0)
    ->propertyCondition('created', REQUEST_TIME - MYMODULE_DELAY, '<')
    ->addTag('DANGEROUS_ACCESS_CHECK_OPT_OUT');

  $result = $query->execute();

  if (isset($result['user'])) {
    $queue = DrupalQueue::get('mymodule_delete_users');
    foreach (array_keys($result['user']) as $uid) {
      $queue->createItem($uid);
    }
  }
}
```

The module should define the constant `MYMODULE_DELAY`, and set it to an appropriate value.

Comment: To implement the 'hostname itself' part, you'd just need to also use `gethostbyname` (well, ideally, `getnameinfo`, but I don't see that in PHP). Or you could just do a good-enough check by doing a `dns_get_record` with a type of `DNS_ANY` (which will get MX, A, and AAAA records, as well as anything else). Big problem you may run into is the check can take several seconds, if nameservers don't respond.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your question, but perhaps solves your problem.

Use a [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) rule or a [hook_cron](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) implementation that removes accounts that have never been logged into, but created more than X days ago.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely at least saves me some manual labor.  Logintoboggan also has an option to do this, but it has a bunch of scary warnings, so I think doing it in Rules would be the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Inactive Users](http://drupal.org/project/inactive_user) module, to send a warning first and then delete the inactive modules.